# d3 circle packing with a gap at the center

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the d3.js pack() method to pack the circles. But I want to leave an empty circle in the center like a gap, and then pack the circles around it. I tried using forceSimulation without luck. I want to achieve something like shown in the picture using pack().

[image: Circles packed with a hollow at the center]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a first Big circle that you don't display

like I did here :

https://observablehq.com/d/220e0ac384e98fd0

```
circles = d3
  .packSiblings([
    {
      r: 100,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      angle: 0
    },
    ...d3
      .range(2000)
      .map(d3.randomUniform(8, 26))
      .map((r) => ({ r }))
  ])
  .filter((d) => -500 < d.x && d.x < 500 && -500 < d.y && d.y < 500)
```

Not displaying first circle

```
...
  .join("circle")
  .attr("fill", (d,i) => i === 0 ? 'none' : color(d.angle = Math.atan2(d.y, d.x)))
  .attr("stroke", (d,i) => i === 0 ? 'none':'black')
...
```

EDIT:
To sort bubbles to have bigger one at center:

```
circles = d3
  .packSiblings([
    {
      r: 100,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      angle: 0
    },
    ...d3
      .range(2000)
      .map(d3.randomUniform(8, 26))
      .map((r) => ({ r }))
      .sort((a, b) => b.r - a.r)
  ])
  .filter((d) => -500 < d.x && d.x < 500 && -500 < d.y && d.y < 500)
```

I also updated my observable to add a sort toggle

Comment: Thank you so much @pernifloss. This really helped a lot. Is there a way I can sort the bubbles so that bigger ones are closer to the center?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include a sort `.sort((a, b) => b.r - a.r)`

Comment: Sorting seems to move the center. Tried with 100 bubbles.

Comment: When I tried with 100 bubbles, the empty circle in the center is moved towards left and not fully centered.

Comment: Did you keep your big circle at the start of your data? Could you please send your code, It's difficult to help you without the context.

Comment: Sure let me add the code in answer section as I can't copy in the comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>

  <script type="module">
    import * as d3 from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7/+esm";

    const width = 954;
    const height = 954;
    const size = Math.max(width, height);
    const color = d3.scaleSequential([0, 2 * Math.PI], d3.interpolateRainbow);
    const circles = d3
      .packSiblings([
        {
          r: 100,
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          angle: 0
        },
        ...d3
          .range(100)
          .map(d3.randomUniform(8, 26))
          .map((r) => ({ r }))
          .sort((a, b) => b.r - a.r)
      ])
    //.filter((d) => -500 < d.x && d.x < 500 && -500 < d.y && d.y < 500);

    const svg = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
      .style("background", "#333")
      .attr("stroke", "currentColor")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);

    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(circles)
      .join("circle")
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => i === 0 ? 'none' : color(d.angle = Math.atan2(d.y, d.x)))
      .attr("stroke", (d, i) => i === 0 ? 'none' : 'black')
      .attr("cx", d => Math.cos(d.angle) * (size / Math.SQRT2 + 30))
      .attr("cy", d => Math.sin(d.angle) * (size / Math.SQRT2 + 30))
      .attr("r", d => d.r - 1)
      .transition()
      .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)
      .delay(d => Math.sqrt(d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y) * 10)
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's still at the center, but you have more circle on the right, it's just an 'optical illusion', you can't do much about it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).